# Accessing objects from a linked list (custom implementation)

Tags: c++, object, linked-list, cout

When using a linked list that stores numerous objects how would you go about access the data inside said object?.

Example code.

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct node                                                
{                                                               
  int data;               
  node* next;             
} *nodePtr;

nodePtr head;
nodePtr current;
nodePtr temp;

void PrintList()
{
    current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->data.getMakeModel();
        cout << current->data.getRegNo();
        cout << current->data.getEngineSize();
        cout << current->data.getRented();

        current=current->next;
    }
}
```

My current way of doing it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to solve it.

All i need to do is access the template object data members which i have getter methods for and output the data.

Any ideas?

On a side note, would it be possible to search for a specific object(an object with specific data member value) in a linked list? with the objects still using templates of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When using a linked list that stores numerous objects how would you go about access the data inside said object?

If you have a `nodePtr` you'll have to do `ptr->data` to access the `int` of the struct.

---

> My current way of doing it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to solve it.

You are trying to access member functions on an object of type `int`, that does not have any. You probably meant to define another type for the `data` member object of `node`.

---

> On a side note, would it be possible to search for a specific object(an object with specific data member value) in a linked list?

Of course, the implementation of such an algorithm is pretty trivial. You can implement it along the lines of:

```
nodePtr find(nodePtr head, int value) {
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next)
        if (*head == value)
            return first;
    return NULL;
}
```

---

What I would suggest is to use the standard `std::forward_list` or `std::list`. If you do, you'll be able to use `std::find` for the "find"-algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The probem here is that `data` is of type `int` and not of a class type. You will have to change its type to a class type e.g `Foo`. A more advanced solution will use templates to make it work with arbitrary types (e.g `std::list`)

---

Also notice that your class definition is not considered good style. I would define it as:

```
struct node                                                
{   
    typedef node* Ptr;

    Foo data;               
    node* next;             
};
```

While the `typedef` is only reasonable in some special cases (e.g if working extensively with smart pointers and reference counting). In normal cases one should go with `node*` (which is also smaller o.O)